# Props not being assigned to data() attribute in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a Vue component, which should refresh restaurants depending on user dynamically selected filters.

Therefor I have to update the `filteredRestaurants` in the `data()` function of my Vue component.
However, at first, when the Vue component is rendered, it takes the restaurant information from the `"restaurants"` prop.

I have tried to insert the `"restaurants"` into the `filteredRestaurants` data attribute to set it as a default value. Unfortunatelly then the stores wouldnt show at tall, as if the  `"restaurants"` prop is inserted after the `filteredRestaurants` is assigned its value.

My question is, how can i get the `"restaurants"` prop into `filteredRestaurants` so that I can later on, re-render the Vue component when the user changes the filters.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="test">
    <Filters></Filters>
  <div>
    <ul class="o-list c-stores">
      <Result v-bind:total="restaurants.length" v-bind:open="isOpen" v-on:toggle="toggleRestaurantList"></Result>
      <li v-for="(restaurant, index) in restaurants" class="c-stores__location" :class="{'first': isFirst(index), 'last': isLast(index, restaurants)}">
        <Location :index="index" :store="restaurant" :link="() => setCurrentRestaurant(restaurant)"></Location>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import eventHub from './../../event-hubs/storefinder'
import Location from './Location'
import Filters from './Filters'
import Result from './Result'

export default {
  props: ["restaurants", "isOpen", "currentSearch"],
  data() {
    return {
      attributes : [],
   // Here I am assigning the prop
      filteredRestaurants : this.restaurants
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: function () {
      return {
        inner: this.$t('storefinder.overview')
      }
    },
    meta: function functionName() {
      return [{
          name: 'og:title',
          content: this.$t('storefinder.overview') + ' - ' + this.$t('storefinder.name'),
          id: "og-title"
        },
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: this.$t('storefinder.description'),
          id: "meta-description"
        },
        {
          name: 'og:description',
          content: this.$t('storefinder.description'),
          id: "og-description"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Location,
    Filters,
    Result
  },
  methods: {
    toggleRestaurantList() {
      eventHub.$emit('showRestaurantList');
    },
    setCurrentRestaurant(restaurant) {
      this.trackRestaurantSelect(restaurant.publicNameSlug);
      this.$router.push({
        name: "store",
        params: {
          restaurant: restaurant.publicNameSlug
        }
      });
    },
    trackRestaurantSelect(restaurantName) {
      dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'GAEvent',
        'eventCategory': 'restaurants',
        'eventAction': 'clickResult',
        'eventLabel': restaurantName,
        'eventValue': undefined,
        'searchTerm': this.currentSearch && this.currentSearch.toLowerCase(),
        'amountSearchResults': 1
      });
    },
    created() {
      eventHub.$on('addFilterTheRestaurants', (attribute) => this.attributes.push(attribute));
      eventHub.$on('removeFilterTheRestaurants', (attribute) => this.attributes = this.attributes.filter(item => item !== attribute));
    },
    isLast: function (idx, list) {
      return idx === list.length - 1;
    },
    isFirst: function (idx) {
      return idx === 0;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

The only way this worked, was when I had the `filteredRestaurants` as a function which returned `"restaurants"`, and I called it inside the Vue template:

```
filteredRestaurants(){
  return this.restaurants
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html):

```
computed: {
  filteredRestaurants() {
    return this.restaurants;
  }
}
```

This will update whenever the value of `this.restaurants` changes.

Comment: But how would I use it in the context of the `v-for(restaurant, index) in restaurants` or `v-bind:total="restaurants.length"` ?

Comment: You reference computed properties just like data. so `v-for="(restaurant, index) in filteredRestaurants"` should work fine.

Comment: For some reason, `v-for="(restaurant, index) in filteredRestaurants"` doesnt work. When I do a `console.log(this.restuarants)` inside the `filteredRestaurants`, I do get the object I am looking for. But it seems like its returning something that the `v-for` nor `v-bind` cant work with :/

Comment: Make sure you're spelling `restaurants` correctly, and that the computed method is returning a value

Comment: Just a follow up question, how would I change the `filteredRestuarants` in the `eventHub.$on` ? I tried this but that didnt seem to work `eventHub.$on('addFilterTheRestaurants', (attribute) => this.filteredRestuarants = function(){return this.restaurants.filter(rest => rest.id === "195500187419-de-ch");})` .
Do you have any other solution for chnging the value of a funtion?